# ¿Cómo puedo hacer hacer la suma en una lista?

Tags: android

Necesito un poco de ayuda.. Me gustaría hacer la suma de los elementos de una fila  en cada rango de mi lista. Estoy usando `ListAdapter` como en la foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
ListView lista;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productos;
String url = "http://Servidor/fcm/select.php";
TextView textView ;
int total =0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_compra);

    new Datas().execute();
}
class Datas extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
        productos = new ArrayList<>();

        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
        Log.d("FINAL", String.valueOf(jsonStr));
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String vende = c.getString("descrip");
                String fecha = c.getString("fecha");
                String detalle = c.getString("detalle");
                HashMap<String, String> contacto = new HashMap<>();
                contacto.put("id", id);
                contacto.put("descrip", vende);
                contacto.put("fecha", fecha);
                contacto.put("detalle", detalle);
                productos.add(contacto);
                Log.d("TIN", String.valueOf(contacto));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        super.onPostExecute(s);
        total++;
        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Compra.this, productos,
                R.layout.item_pedidos, new String[]{"id", "descrip", "fecha", "detalle"},
                new int[]{R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4, R.id.textView5});
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

         total= lista.getAdapter().getCount();
       Log.d("TOTAL", String.valueOf(total));// Aqui solo llego a contar el nombre de elementos que esta en la lista...
        String res = ""+total;
        textView.setText(res);
      registerForContextMenu(lista);

    }
}
```

Muchas gracias...

Comment: Deberías mostrar el código correspondiente para que te puedan ayudar

Comment: Edite la pregunta con el codigo incuido Gracias @aldanux

Comment: Por favor comparte el código del Producto.java y el Adapter del producto. Ya que se me hace muy extraño que el valor a sumar del mismo sea su ID porque al obtener los valores de la base no obtienes algun campo que sea parecido a un "valor" o "cantidad", y me da la sensación de que el mismo lo obtienes de algun otro lado. Saludos.

Comment: No tengo codigo de Producto .. estoy recibiendo los valores desde un servidor en json... productos es el nombre que lo de a mi ArrayList para rellenar la lista con los resultados del json.....(Lo voy a modificar el codigo completo)

Answer (score 1):

Okey vamos a ver, suponiendo que productos, es una arreglo que contiene toda la info que se muestra en la lista, y que id es el valor que guarda la cantidad de elementos por cada producto (estoy suponiendo, tu código no es muy claro) quedaría algo así:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    total++;
    final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Compra.this, productos,
            R.layout.item_pedidos, new String[]{"id", "descrip", "fecha", "detalle"},
            new int[]{R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4, R.id.textView5});
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    in total = 0;
    for (Producto element : productos){
        total = total + element.getId(); //pon el valor que guarda la cantidad de unidades por producto aqui.
    }
    Log.d("TOTAL", String.valueOf(total));// Aqui solo llego a contar el nombre de elementos que esta en la lista...
    String res = ""+total;
    textView.setText(res);
    registerForContextMenu(lista);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mi propuesta es la siguiente; Como ya estas recorriendo el Json al obtener los elementos, aprovechar dicho ciclo para convertir el elemento `id` a un entero tipo `int` e ir sumándolo. Para después en tu `onPostExecute` tener ya la cantidad total de la suma de todas las filas.

```
ListView lista;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productos;
String url = "http://Servidor/fcm/select.php";
TextView textView ;
int total =0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_compra);

    new Datas().execute();
}
class Datas extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
        productos = new ArrayList<>();

        total = 0;
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
        Log.d("FINAL", String.valueOf(jsonStr));
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String vende = c.getString("descrip");
                String fecha = c.getString("fecha");
                String detalle = c.getString("detalle");
                HashMap<String, String> contacto = new HashMap<>();
                contacto.put("id", id);
                contacto.put("descrip", vende);
                contacto.put("fecha", fecha);
                contacto.put("detalle", detalle);
                productos.add(contacto);
                Log.d("TIN", String.valueOf(contacto));
                //vas sumando los elementos
                total = total + Integer.parseInt(id);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        super.onPostExecute(s);
        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Compra.this, productos,
            R.layout.item_pedidos, new String[]{"id", "descrip", "fecha", "detalle"},
            new int[]{R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4, R.id.textView5});
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

       Log.d("TOTAL", String.valueOf(total));// Aqui solo llego a contar el nombre de elementos que esta en la lista...
        String res = ""+total;
        textView.setText(res);
      registerForContextMenu(lista);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pienso que la mejor solución sería utilizar los argumentos de la tarea asíncrona, te dejo el código modificado:

```
ListView lista;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productos;
String url = "http://Servidor/fcm/select.php";
TextView textView ;
int total =0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_compra);

    new Datas().execute();
}
class Datas extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
        productos = new ArrayList<>();
        String total;

        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
        Log.d("FINAL", String.valueOf(jsonStr));
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
            int sumTotal = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                sumTotal += Integer.parseInt(c.getString("id"));  //Aquí haces la sumatoria de la columna
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String vende = c.getString("descrip");
                String fecha = c.getString("fecha");
                String detalle = c.getString("detalle");
                HashMap<String, String> contacto = new HashMap<>();
                contacto.put("id", id);
                contacto.put("descrip", vende);
                contacto.put("fecha", fecha);
                contacto.put("detalle", detalle);
                productos.add(contacto);
                Log.d("TIN", String.valueOf(contacto));

            }
            total = String.valueOf(sumTotal);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return total; // regresas la sumatoria en string para que en onPostExecute lo puedas leer
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        super.onPostExecute(s);
        total++;
        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Compra.this, productos,
                R.layout.item_pedidos, new String[]{"id", "descrip", "fecha", "detalle"},
                new int[]{R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4, R.id.textView5});
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

         total= lista.getAdapter().getCount();
        String res = ""+total;
        textView.setText(s);
      registerForContextMenu(lista);

    }
}
```

Harías la sumatoria dentro de `doInBackground()` y después retornar en el mismo método el total de la columna, al final sólo tendrías que tomar el parámetro de `onPostExecute()` y setearlo en el `textView`.

Comment: Esto sería lo ideal, doInBackground() retorna el valor (total) que es usado en onPostExecute()